# text formatting according to indentation

Tags: html, wysiwyg, word-processor, openwysiwyg

Hi can someone help me understand how the stackoverflow question's code area works(technically). 
I mean the way it formats the text as it indent the text.

example: without indentation

```
 example: with indentation ( text background color and font has changed)
```

can someone explain me the technology behind this. I am new to programming, is this something hard to implement. How can we implement this kind of formatting depending on the indentation of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to loop through each line of text in a string, and group them by indentation level into sections:

```
var leadingSpaces = /^\s*/;
blockOfText = blockOfText.replace(/\t/g, '    '); // replace tabs with 4 spaces
var lines = blockOfText.split('\n');
var sections = [];
var currentIndentLevel = null;
var currentSection = null;
lines.forEach(function(line) {
    var indentLevel = leadingSpaces.exec(line)[0].length;
    if (indentLevel !== currentIndentLevel) {
        currentIndentLevel = indentLevel;
        currentSection = { indentLevel: currentIndentLevel, lines: [] };
        sections.push(currentSection);
    }
    currentSection.lines.push(line);
});
```

Then, once you have those sections, you can loop through them:

```
sections.forEach(function(section) { 
    switch (section.indentLevel) {
        case 4:
            // format as code
            break;
        // etc.
        default:
            // format as markdown
            break;
    }
});
```